# Sage Pay - Not returning session id in the querystring

Tags: payment-gateway

Has anybody experienced a problem with SagePay not returning the session id back after a transaction.

Cheers

Shane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it this end:

http://keyzo.co.uk/blog/wordpress-wp-ecommerce-and-sagepay/

Hope it helps somebody else.